# joinLeft error: constructor cannot be instantiated to expected type

Tags: scala, slick

I'm converting some code from Slick 2.1 to 3.0.3, and when I migrated my join from using `leftJoin` to `joinLeft` I'm receiving this error and I'm not sure how to solve it:

```
[error] ContentRepoLocal.scala:84: constructor cannot be instantiated to expected type;  
[error]  found   : (T1, T2)  
[error]  required: slick.lifted.Rep[Option[(repo.model.UserContentTable, repo.model.ContentTable)]]  
[error]           .map { case (u, (uc, c)) => (u, c.optionProjection) }  
[error]                           ^  
[error] ContentRepoLocal.scala:84: diverging implicit expansion for type slick.lifted.Shape[_ <: slick.lifted.FlatShapeLevel, Nothing, T, G]  
[error] starting with method repColumnShape in trait RepShapeImplicits  
[error]           .map { case (u, (uc, c)) => (u, c.optionProjection) }
```

On this code:

```
def getContentsByUser(userId: UUID): Either[UserNotFoundError, List[Content]] = {

 val subQuery =
   for {
     uc <- UserContentTable.query if uc.userId === userId.toString && (!uc.adopted.isDefined || !uc.adopted)
     c <- ContentTable.query if uc.contentId === c.id
   } yield (uc, c)


 val query =
   UserTable.query.filter(_.id === userId.toString)
     .joinLeft(subQuery).on { case (u, (uc, c)) => u.id === uc.userId}
     .map { case (u, (uc, c)) => (u, c.optionProjection) }

 //...

}
```

**EDIT 1:**

Got a little bit further with this by refactoring my subQuery to use the `for` comprehension syntax:

```
val query =
  for (
    (u, t) <- UserTable.query.filter(_.id === userId.toString) joinLeft subQuery on { case (u, (uc, c)) => u.id === uc.userId }
  ) yield (u, t)
```

This compiles. However, according to the [documentation](http://slick.lightbend.com/doc/3.0.0/queries.html#applicative-joins) the `yield` should be applying `t.map(_)` to convert `Null` values to `None`.

So when I refactor the line to read:

`yield (u, t.map(_))`

I get the error:

```
[error] missing parameter type for expanded function ((x$2) => t.map(x$2))
[error]       ) yield (u, t.map(_))
[error]                         ^
[error] one error found
```

**EDIT 2 :** You can find a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example [here](https://github.com/ctataryn/slick3-problems).

**EDIT 3:** Confirmed this issue exists in Slick `3.1.1` as well

Comment: You should post definitions of your tables, because without them we won't be able to reproduce your error.

Comment: @PawełJurczenko I've created a project to isolate and demonstrate the problem. It should help fill in the blanks https://github.com/ctataryn/slick3-problems

Comment: You have confused the issue with Edit1, which is asking us to solve a completely different error.   If someone comes here on a search for the first error message, they expect to find an answer to _that_.

Comment: @GreenAsJade I believe it is the same error in that the type of the tuple is not being inferred.

Comment: Ah - that's not obvious to me: is there more error message in the Edit case, that you didn't share?

Comment: @GreenAsJade That's about it :(  I think this may be a bug. Something that worked in 2.1.x but now doesn't in 3.0.x

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`joinLeft` joins `subQuery` as `Option` in Slick3. In this case, you have to re-map `subQuery` as follows:

```scala
val query =
   UserTable.query.filter(_.id === userId.toString)
     .joinLeft(subQuery).on { case (u, (uc, c)) => u.id === uc.userId}
     .map { case (u, sub) => (u, sub.map { case (uc, c) => c }) }
```